# SendKeys.SendWait("^c") not working correctly in MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor project

Tags: c#, hook

I want to get selected word when I double click on a word in other application. So, I customize the **HookManager_MouseDoubleClick** method of [MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor](https://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/). But the **SendKeys.SendWait("^c")** didn't work correctly when putting it in **HookManager_MouseDoubleClick** method(it only get the "" string or all text string of a line although I double click a word ) , I can't get the selected word. With the same way, the [GlobalHookDemo](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C) works correctly. I don't know the reason why **SendKeys.SendWait("^c")** doesn't work correctly in the first project.Please help me.Thank in advance!

This is my code:

```
private void HookManager_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Clipboard.Clear();
       SendKeys.SendWait("^c");
        Log(string.Format("MouseDoubleClick \t\t {0}\n", Clipboard.GetText()));
    }
```

Comment: Are you in the main thread ? Are you sure it's `Sendwait` which doesn't work (try to paste with CTRL+V after doubleClicking to check  if `^c` is well send )?
I had some issues using SendWait (it worked only once), so i used InputSimulator library to send keystroke which works fine, but Clipboard.GetText () was the cause of my issues because it was throw from another Thread.

Comment: Sendwait("^c") doesn't work correctly  as I talk above not doesn't work.I test this Sendwait("^c") in two project above,only the first project, the Sendwait("^c") worked not correctly.